# Need fix an unusual window behavior Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, filemanager

I've upgraded from Ubuntu Utopic to the 16.04 and when I go to my file explorer I got the problem in the picture.

How can I fix it?

[image: File Explorer]

[image: File Explorer 2]